# Eclipse PDE: programmatically launch application and redirect output

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Eclipse Luna on JDK1.8. I have a simple java program that will print "Hello World" on console using System.out. In Eclipse PDE, I need to programmatically launch this program. I use the following code snippet:

```
config.launch(ILaunchManager.RUN_MODE, null);
```

The launch is successful. I saw the Hello World message on the console of the new IDE. The problem is how to get the message printed on a in-house developed Console which extends IOConsole? That is, I want to see the message printed on my own Console class, not the default one in Eclipse.

Or if I don't use a custom Console, is there any way to redirect the IOConsoleOutputStream? The class extends OutputStream but it is not allowed to be instantiated using constructor. So I cannot redirect it in the way as a regular OutputStream does by passing a ByteArrayOutputStream.

Thanks for help.

Comment: One way would be to use the `org.eclipse.debug.core.launchConfigurationTypes` extension point to define a new launch type. This gives you complete control of how the program is launched - but requires quite a lot of code (and research to find out what the code has to do!)

Comment: Thank you for the help. I will spend some time on the approach!

Comment: Did you ever find an answer? I'm looking for something similar.